# Does there exist a method in C# to get the relative path given two absolute path inputs?

Tags: c#, .net, path, relative-path

Does there exist a method in C# to get the relative path given two absolute path inputs?

That is I would have two inputs (with the first folder as the base) such as

```
c:\temp1\adam\
```

and

```
c:\temp1\jamie\
```

Then the output would be

```
..\jamie\
```

Comment: I can't quite bring myself to +1 for the Mythbusters reference. Oh go on then!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way, but this will work:

```
var file1 = @"c:\temp1\adam\";
var file2 = @"c:\temp1\jamie\";

var result = new Uri(file1)
    .MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file2))
    .ToString()
    .Replace("/", "\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

this is simple. Steps:

1. Remove common beginning of string (`c:\temp1\`)
2. Count number of directories of first path (1 in your case)
3. Replace them with ..
4. Add second path

Comment: but you don't know the common prefix! (step 1)

Comment: Finding the common prefix of two strings isn't that hard. The problem lies in the details. Both / and \ are path seperators, some filesystems are case-insensitive, others are case-sensitive, a path can contain . or .. and probably several other issues. On the other hand underestimating the common part isn't that big a problem.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat i thought it is obvious

Comment: @CodeInChaos: i didn't say it was hard.

Answer (score 2):

Updated: since the constructor is now obsolete you can use:

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString(new Uri(file1).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file2)).ToString())
  .Replace("/", "\\");
```

---

old version:

Kirk Woll's idea is good but you need to ensure your path doesn't get mangled (e.g. spaces replaced by %20) by telling Uri not to escape your path:

```
var result = new Uri(file1, true)
    .MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file2, true))
    .ToString()
    .Replace("/", "\\");
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought this was a good point, but it bears mentioning that that constructor is considered obsolete and will generate a compiler warning.  In my testing, I did not have any issues with escaped characters.  I wonder what characters were being escaped for you?

Comment: @Kirk Woll, I had problems with spaces in the name.

Comment: Ah, duh, sorry, didn't realize you had mentioned that.  Thanks for responding.